# Is it ok to kill the sh zombie process?

Tags: linux, process, kill, ps

sh process is zombie but
i have doubts killing it in case it will affect the parent crond(31720), since it's in an enterprise server.

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND

root     31721  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Zs   17:00   0:00 [sh] defunct> 

pstree -p 1967
crond(1967)───crond(31720)───sh(31721)

lsof -p 31721
```

returns nothing, so no open files.

Comment: I think it won't be affecting.

Comment: You can't really kill the process since it's already dead, see: http://superuser.com/questions/454385/should-i-kill-zombie-process-in-my-system?rq=1